Possible to use Advanced Pricing with Swatches/Configurable Product?
I work within a B2B environment and would love to use swatches for colors/sizes of things (so I don't need to have 4 separate product pages for 4 skus, but they can all be accessed on one page), but the issue that I am seeing with that and using Configurable products/swatches, is that they only allow one single price, and with my B2B store, there could be 5+ prices attached to each item.
Is there any way to utilize the advanced pricing option seen in creating a simple product (or something to that affect) while using a configurable product?
Alternatively, is there any other method to allow for, say all 4 of a multi-colored product to be displayed and on one product page, with advanced pricing for each sku, that will change the image/pricing/name of the selected option all within that single product page?

After creating the configurable products along with their configurations, you can establish advanced pricing for the associated simple products. This can be done by editing each individual simple product once they have been created.
